# How to use Rx to manage multiple observers in order to keep only one open connection to a service?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

In my application, some Activities get information from the server and I need to ensure that the connection was already established before trying to retrieve the data. I'm using a BehaviorSubject to notify the subscribers when the connection is established, so the Activity can load the data.

The issue is that more than one activity in the same flow have the same behavior. In our API we must call `connect()` in the `onStart()` and `disconnect()` in `onStop`, but if the user goes the another Activity that also uses connection, there's no need to recreate the connection, we could use the same.

At the moment, I'm implementing in the following way:

- When you call `connect()` it returns an `BehaviorSubject` that will be subscribed from the calling class
- On method `disconnect()`, it only actually disconnects if there is no observers in the `BehaviorSubject`, indicating that no Activities are waiting for the response.
- The calling class **must** dispose the Observable before calling the `disconnect()`, otherwise the method `hasObservers()` will never return `false`

  ```
  @CheckResult
  @Override
  public BehaviorSubject<Boolean> connect() {
     if (!connectionManager.isConnected()) {
          connectionManager.connect(TIMEOUT);
     }

     return mSubject;
  }

  @Override
  public void disconnect() {
      if (connectionManager.isConnected() && !mSubject.hasObservers()){
          connectionManager.disconnect();
      }
  }
  ```

In my previous implementation, I was using listeners to achieve this. Every time `connect()` is called, it must receive the listener as a parameter that will be added in a Array of listeners and later notified one by one when the connection was established.

And every time `disconnect()` is called it also must receive the listener as a parameter to be removed from the list. The `connectionManager.disconnect()` will only be called if the Array of listeners is null, indicating that no Activities are waiting for the response.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Can you give me caller's code. If you use `doOnDispose(()->disconnect())`, it will fail as expected. Because it will be called before the `Disposable` disposed.(See `DisposableLambdaObserver#dispose`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you create your subject, you can specify what needs to happen when someone subscribes/unsubscribes:

```
subject.doOnUnsubscribe(()-> {
  if(!subject.hasObservers()) {
    closeConnection();
  }
});
subject.doOnSubscribe(() -> {
  openConnectionIfNotOpen();
});
```

This way, you can get rid of the `disconnect()` call, you just have to unsubscribe